# Flutter Isar-ORM obtaining all related links from collection

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-isar

You suppose we created this collection for `Isar`:

```dart
@collection
class Teacher {
  Id id;

  late String subject;

  @Backlink(to: 'teacher')
  final student = IsarLinks<Student>();
}
```

as you can see `student` is a `Isar` link and i research all `Isar` documentation to know how can i have all `student` from `Teacher` like a tree such as: `teacher.students`

for example:

```dart
teacher = isarInstance.collection<Teacher>().where().findFirstSync();

print(teacher.students);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out

solution is:

```dart
teacher = isarInstance.collection<Teacher>().where().findFirstSync();

print(teacher.value!.students);
```